# Improve the User Interface of Website

Tags: html, css, silverlight, ajax

So I am using Visual Studio 2008, ASP.net 3.5, with the basic toolkit provided.

Now I have made the GUI with a lot of functionality but the design is very basic and looks too old.

I need to give it a new look, new feeling and new design....like the gridview, the buttons the textboxes, the menus look basic... this is not working for me.

Please let me know how should I go about doing this?

1) I have heard about tool kits but don't know which ones are good..(don't want the really expensive ones) but if it is really good, my company is ready to spend.

2) Will the new VS 2010 or ASP.net 4.0 make a difference?

3) Is Ajax toolkit or Silverlight toolkit any good?

4) I also need to show Charts and graphs. Currently I am using MS charts.. but now I need which is good.

Comment: Do you have a design question? If your question is purely about toolkits, ask on StackOverflow or Doctype. User Interface is for design issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered jqueryui? They have a CSS theme generator that's been a good starting point for me.

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Twitter bootstrap.

- It too allows customisation, but looks better especially the buttons
- It is responsive so works on mobile and tablet too
- The [button grouping](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups) and [button dropdowns](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns) are really useful
- has a wider range of Icons, plus there's [tutorials on how to customise the icons](http://favbulous.com/post/1006/create-custom-icons-for-twitter-bootstrap-easily)